# Custom LegacyWrapper for vaadin flow to integrated legacy code

Tags: wrapper, legacy, vaadin-flow

There are plenty of good addons, developed for vaadin 7 and vaadin 8 non compatible with flow. Searching for solution i found - [vaadin docs on MPR (multiplatform runtime)](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/mpr/configuration/adding-legacy-components.html) - where `LegacyWrapper` class is available which provides integration for legacy components into flow engine. The MPR is available for Prime (paid) subscription users only, so does the `LegacyWrapper` class as well. 
Could anybody please give any hints how to make a simple wrapper implementation for using legacy components into flow layouts. I believe, supposed `CustomLegacyWrapper` class should inherit from `vaadin.flow.component` and contain (as a composition, maybe?) `vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent`. How the baseline solution might look like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an answer to my question on the vaadin forum from one of the contributors that there is no simple workaround for my purpose, integration of old components into flow engine is one of multiplatform features and its not possible to implement it in easy way.